# Custom UICollectionViewCell and memory leak when using UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. When scrolling left and right (it is a horizontal `UICollectionView`, memory usage increases by 0.2MB each time.

I believe I am correctly implementing `prepareForReuse()` in the cell object; within it I remove all subviews of the cell.

With `didSet` of an object on my collection view cell, I call `setupViews()` within my cell. I add a `UIImageView` with constraints and add it as a subview. This is fine.

However, when I use a `UILabel()`, this is when there seems to be a memory leak. When I look in Instruments, I can see: *VM: UILabel (CALayer)* is repeatedly created every time I scroll between two cells! This does not happen with the `UIImageView`.

Just in case it's relevant, here's my `prepareForReuse` method in my cell:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.moreButtonDelegate = nil

    for subview in subviews {
        subview.removeConstraints(subview.constraints)
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    self.removeFromSuperview() // BURN EVERYTHING
}
```

Here's my code:

```
private func setupViews() -> Void {
    let imageView = myImageView // A lazy class property returns this

    innerView.addSubview(imageView) // innerView is just another UIView within this cell

    // Now I add constraints for imageView
}
```

So with the above, **there's no memory leak**. Looks like ARC cleans everything up correctly as, even with an image, memory usage does not increase exponentially.

However, when I add this below `imageView`...

```
let address = UILabel()
address.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
address.text = "TEST"
address.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
address.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

// Then I add constraints
```

I get a new `VM: UILabel (CALayer)` row appearing on every scroll between cells, and as a result memory usage jumps. Take a look:

[image: ui label memory leak]

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Xcode 9, iOS 11.2 simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this will resolve your particular issue, but I believe you misunderstood `prepareForReuse` and I think there is a good chance that this might be what's wrong with your code. So lets take a look at your implementation:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.moreButtonDelegate = nil

    for subview in subviews {
        subview.removeConstraints(subview.constraints)
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    self.removeFromSuperview() // BURN EVERYTHING
}
```

I believe you are looking at the `prepareForReuse` totally wrong. The main point of the reuse is to reduce the overhead caused by creating the view of the cell (objects instantiation, creating the view hierarchy, layout, etc.). You don't want to burn everything! Instead, you want to keep as much of the contentView as possible. Ideally, you will change just the contents of the views (i.e.: `text` in `UILabel`, `image` in `UIImageView`, etc.), or maybe some properties (`backgroundColor`, etc.).

You can use `prepareForReuse` to cancel some heavyweight operations that you started to present the cell, but that might not have ended when the cell was removed from view and is supposed to be reused somewhere else. E.g., when you download content from web, user might scroll fast, and the cell goes away from the screen before the web image was downloaded and presented. Now if the cell gets reused, the old downloaded image will be most probably shown - so in `prepareForReuse` you can cancel this operation.

Conclusion - I believe in your case none of the operations you are doing in `prepareForReuse` really help - vice versa, because of that the collection view will have to again recreate the whole UI of the cell again from scratch (that means all the overhead of object instantiation, etc.). My first advice for you is to drop the whole `prepareForReuse` implementation.

Second, once you drop your `prepareForReuse` implementation, refactor the cell so that it will create the UI only once, ideally in its `initializer`:

```
class UI: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupViews()
    }
}
```

Then, in `cellForItemAt` just configure its contents, that means set texts for labels, images for image views, etc.

In the end, keep in mind what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse) says about it (my own emphasis):

> Performs any clean up **necessary** to prepare the view for use again.

Do only what is really necessary to do, not a thing more.

Over the last year I have implemented many `tableView` and `collectionView` datasources, but I really needed to use `prepareForReuse` just twice (for the example with image download I mentioned above).

**EDIT**

Example of what I meant:

```
struct Model {
    var name: String = ""
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    // create it once
    private let nameLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // setup view once
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        // add it to view
        self.contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        // setup configuration
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red

        // lay it out
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -8),
            ])
    }

    // this is what you call in cellForRowAt
    func configure(for model: Model) {
        nameLabel.text = model.name
        // someImageView.image = model.image
        // etc.
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // if it is super important, reset the content, cancel operations, etc., but there is no reason to recreate the UI

        // so e.g. this might be ok (although in this case completely unnecessary):
        nameLabel.text = nil

        // but you definitely don't want to do this (that's done once at the cell initialization):
        // nameLabel = UILabel()
        // setupViews()
    }
}
```

```
class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var models: [Model] = [Model(name: "Milan")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        // you just want to set the contents, not to recreate the UI components
        cell.configure(for: models[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Moreover, always work with cell's `contentView`, not directly with the cell. Notice that I used this:

```
self.contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
```

instead of this:

```
self.addSubview(nameLabel)
```

[Official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview):

> The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation of `prepareForReuse` Milan - you've cleared up a lot for me with your very succinct answer, it's really helpful, cheers!

Comment: Adding it as an optional and setting it to nil afterwards doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Jimbo Are you sure that you wanted to write that comment here? I don't understand the context. Adding what as an optional?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, you suggest *changing* the labels instead of re-creating them. This would require me to store the label as a class member, therefore an optional. I did that, and in prepare for reuse just as a test, I set it to nil, but it is still re-created each time therefore the memory leak still exists :/

Comment: Weird thing which I might add to the question, if I directly add the UILabel with `addSubview`, it works, no memory leak. The problem: if I create a UIView to contain this, and then call addSubview on that, that's where the memory leak exists. Any ideas? If not I'll update the above

Comment: @Jimbo I think you still haven't understood what I was trying to tell you. Look at the example I have provided in the updated question. For each label that is supposed to be in the cell, you want to call `UILabel()` only once! No optionals, no variables, simply let constant initialized at the beginning. After that, you just change it's attributes, specifically only text, unless it is necessary to change something else.

Comment: Ahhh, I have a setter that I call that changes the contents of the cell instead of creating new ones. I understand you now. Let me give it a shot, thanks for the additional clarification. I still think that what I found originally was a bug, although this will solve it in a different way, but I'll try it now

Comment: @Jimbo since I don't have the whole project of yours, it's hard to pinpoint the exact source, but I have a suspicion that while you have created new components, the old one that you tried to throw away were retained for some reason. that would keep the labels alive and cause memory leaks.. So I really don't think it's a bug in apple's code

Comment: Thanks Milan, your answer is super useful!! I know this post may not get too many views, but you've been really helpful and I'll use this knowledge for the future. Cheers dude!

Comment: While I think that your code shouldn't create in theory a memory leak (maybe a timing issue), I agree with @MilanNosáľ. You understood that cells are reuse and clean your cell, but you don't profit of the reuse to just reuses theses view already created (alloc/init done each time).